# Decrement the number in other component in angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 component

1. Left Component
2. Main Component

**Left Component**

In left component there is button which clicks only 5 time. Once its reach to 5, button disabled

```
<button
   class="btn gbtn ml-3"
   [disabled]="query_limit! > 4"
   (click)="createQuery()"> Create Query
</button>

createQuery() {
    this.query_limit = this.query_limit + 1;
}
```

**Main Component**

In this component, there is button which suppose to decrements this `query_limit`.

Its seems like counter but increment and decrements is separated in 2 different component.
I am trying to find the solution how to do this?

Any Help?

Comment: If the main component and left component have parent child relationship, you could use the `@Input` and `@Output` decorator to communicate between the two components.
If both of your components are sister components you could use an injectable service to share data between two components.
 https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce an intermediate service to communicate between the components,

```
export class CartDataService {

  private Count = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  cast = this.Count.asObservable();
  currentCount: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  editCount(newCount: number){
    this.currentCount += newCount; 
    this.Count.next(this.currentCount);
  }

}
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p69ka7?file=app%2Fcartdata.service.ts)**

Comment: I like your answer to go with an intermediate service. I have a question. Shall I use intermediate service when components have relationship like parent child. What would be the best approach `@Input` and `@Output` or a intermediate service?

Comment: If you are sure that you are going to have a dependency always, then go with input output bindings. Services are mainly for components which are not related

Comment: If the components are in the **same page** and in the **same router-outlet** you can also use a template reference to referered to a component. Remember that the variables of a component by defect are public

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you need to use ViewChild to get a refrence of Child comp

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohk6iq

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent,{static : false}) Child: ChildComponent;
    DrecreaseQuery() {
      if(this.Child.query_limit>0){
          this.Child.query_limit = this.Child.query_limit - 1;
      }    
  }
}
```